# Why won't my IDEA projects build?

Tags: intellij-idea, build, compiler-errors, kotlin

I am building [a software platform](https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Blue-Husky-Software-Platform), and as a proof of concept (and to determine what it requires), I'm building an instant messenger called Telegram RP, using my platform repos listed here: https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Blue-Husky-Software-Platform

Now, I've made the decision to separate the JVM-specific code from the generic code, but upon my first step doing so, it won't compile.

I'm stumped. I've triple-checked language-level visibilities, removed and re-added both Git and IDEA modules, triple-checked the dependency hierarchies, ensured parallel builds are off... and yet **it still claims that there's an unresolved reference at build time**, despite the editor letting me middle-/control-click to navigate to the import.

Can anyone help me understand how to make this understand that the package it's complaining about is actually there when I click build andor run?

---

#### I encourage you to clone these and attempt to build them in IDEA 2017.2:

Here's **an SSCCE of my setup**, which should compile just fine once all repos are cloned: https://github.com/BenLeggiero/SO-SSCCE-45271471

Here's the repo containing the project in question: https://github.com/BenLeggiero/Telegram-RP <sub>([permalink to repo when I asked this question](https://github.com/BenLeggiero/Telegram-RP/tree/60c7b026fd4bd09a0b348dec6e44a4a52326f7b1))</sub>

Specifically, this sub-repo: https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Husky-UI/tree/For-Telegram-RP

Here's the line that's failing: https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Husky-UI/blob/6887f492c37583d82b49ebf36b12d68a3a1dcb32/JVM/src/org/bh/tools/ui/swing/Graphics%20Extensions.kt#L8

```
import org.bh.tools.ui.generic.geometry.FractionOval
                       ^ ~~~~~
Error:(8, 24) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: generic
```

---

This didn't happen before I moved Desktop-JVM-specific code [from Husky UI/Core](https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Husky-UI/commit/7bb78188cc5e66c52ba012cdb6aa6ded71926cdf), [to Husky UI/JVM](https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Husky-UI/commit/50ba2dcf6bd3520e17dc927aec82cd5fb88f266e), so I must assume it involves that... I just can't figure out why.

---

My environment:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 
>   Build #IC-172.3317.76, built on July 15, 2017 
>   JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b5 amd64 
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o 
>   Windows 10 10.0

Comment: Is this a class you created?  A Google search revealed little for `FractionOval`.

Comment: This seems like an import problem. Are you using gradle?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. It's at https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Husky-UI/blob/For-Telegram-RP/JVM/src/org/bh/tools/ui/generic/geometry/Oval.kt#L26

Comment: @Beryllium no, I'm using IDEA and git modules

Comment: Are you using Maven?  Gradle?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just using IDEA's built-in build system

Comment: If IntelliSense is working, but it can't build, then the only possibility which comes to mind is that this dependency is not on your class path.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I agree. I just can't figure out what that is, exactly

Comment: Well what is the location of the JAR file, and are there other dependencies in the same location which _are_ being picked up correctly when you build?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There's no JAR, yet; currently, the whole project and its (my) libraries are being built every time. The rest of the Husky UI libraries and Blue Base are being picked up just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149953/discussion-between-ben-leggiero-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: If you are including this dependency as actual source code rather than a JAR, then I think you'd need to use the same package path.  Does a file called `org.bh.tools.ui.generic.geometry.FractionOval` exist in your project?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `FractionOval` exists only in Husky UI/Core, and Husky UI/JVM has a compile-time dependency on Husky UI/Core. Neither my top-level project, Telegram RP, nor any of the other libraries, contain a `FractionOval`. If they did, I'd get a conflict error rather than a missing symbol error. I encourage you to clone the projects and see the build error, yourself.

Comment: I upvoted your question if that helps.

Comment: Thank you, @TimBiegeleisen. I will continue trying to fix it myself, as well, and update with an answer if I find one. I'll definitely give it a bounty, too, if it comes to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is all about module name changes after your refactoring, so the dependencies cannot be found.

1.
In `Telegram-RP/lib/Husky-UI/JVM/Husky UI JVM/JVM.iml` changes

```
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky UI/Core" exported="" />
```

to

```
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky UI"  exported="" />
```

---

2.
In `Telegram-RP/Desktop JVM/Desktop JVM.iml`

changes

```
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky UI/Core" />
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky UI/JVM" />
```

to

```
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky UI" />
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="JVM" />
```

---

As a matter of fact, you can see module names from the `Project` view in bold text :
[image]

Comment: Oh oops! I think I understand now. This is essentially the same solution as @cristianoms', correct?

Comment: @BenLeggiero Yes, but I think I am the first to have the correct answer, you can see from the timeline and my edit history .

Comment: Your got it right about an our before me, @aristotll. The only thing you missed is about editing source code inside git submodules, which you shouldn't do.

Answer (score 4):

Got it figured after messing around a while. I'll post the `git diff` output so you can apply it directly to your files.

First, there's changes to be done in the submodule `lib/Husky-UI/JVM/Husky UI JVM/JVM.iml` (remember: you should edit the proper repository and update this project's git submodule):

```
-    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky UI/Core" exported="" />
+    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky UI" exported="" />
```

Then go after `Core/Core.iml` and remove those 2 lines:

```
-    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky UI/Core" />
-    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky UI/JVM" />
```

Finally,change `Desktop JVM/Desktop JVM.iml`:

```
+    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky UI" exported="" />
+    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky IO" exported="" />
+    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="JVM" exported="" />
     <orderEntry type="module" module-name="Blue Base" />
-    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky IO" />
     <orderEntry type="module" module-name="Core" />
-    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky UI/Core" />
-    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="Husky UI/JVM" />
```

Tell me how it worked out for you.

Comment: Oh wow that made it build! Can you explain why? Also, this is essentially the same as @aristotll's answer, right?

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda the same thing. The only thing missing in @aristotll's answer is that you're not supposed to edit the submodules configuration files directly. But in the end it's all about dependencies and their paths :)

Comment: I'm all for editing "gui-only" files in the name of "no, IDE, you messed up this time" :P

Comment: haha I'm the opposite. Actually, I hate committing IDE's specific project configuration files to source control. I rather having them automatically generated for me. Check how to do it with Gradle: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html